# what are pervasive applications

Tags: native, pervasive

I know this isnt a question with code in it. But ive been searching the internet for the answer and cant find it anywhere. 
What is a pervasive app?
And why are native apps essential in their development?

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense to me.  You have tagged Pervasive...you do mean the Pervasive SQL database engine, right?  What "native apps" are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

A pervasive in an app (usually mobile app) that adapts at runtime to its external environment. For example, it uses geolocalization, phone sensors, externals sensors (ex. surrounding air quality sensors), surrounding data (ex. yp places database) and so on to provide a highly personalized user experience. Pervasive apps are also called context-aware apps.